# Difference Between .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter-2

What is the difference between,

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /myproject/index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

and

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /myproject/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Difference is between regex which is:

- `.*` **(0 or more characters)**
- `.+` **(1 or more characters)**

`QSA` is not really needed in 1st rule and not making any difference to outcome.